# Barber shop vs Barbershop?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I've met both usages:

- [Barbershop](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/barbershop)
- [Barber shop](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/barber-shop) ([Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Barber%20Shop))

I've also notices that some write **barber's shop**.

Are they different in UK and US and which one prevails over the other?

If I wish to say that I want my hair cut, do I say?

- I want to cut my hair, I need to see a barber!
- I want to cut my hair, I need to go to the barbershop (barber's shop, barber shop)!

Comment: (At least in the UK) It would be common to leave off "shop" entirely and use "barber's" (in the same way as you might for butcher's etc.). E.g. "I'm going to the barber's for a haircut."

Comment: @SteveES With an apostrophe? Why not **to the barber**? What about **"dentist","doctor"**? Do you also say **to the dentist's**, **to the doctor's**?

Comment: Yes I would, if I were talking about the surgery (i.e. the premises). I would only generally have cause to **say** it though, so I wouldn't particularly think about the apostrophe, but it would have an "s" on the end!

Comment: As far as Google Ngrams can be trusted, it looks like *barbershop* is definitely the preferred form in the US.  In the UK, *barber's shop* used to be the preferred form but has been losing ground to *barbershop*.  Note that the popularity of *barbershop* may be influenced by [barbershop quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbershop_quartet), which I think is only ever written that way.

Comment: @stangdon Yeh, I looked at the NGram, but I certainly would like a now-time answer. In Russian any form is correct and preferred. We can say:** "I need to go to the barber (a person)."** or **"I need to go to the barbershop (the place where a barber works)."**

Comment: As an aside, if I were talking about a specific type of a cappella group, I would use "barbershop" (as in barbershop quartet).

Comment: In some regions, while barber shops *exist*, they are not always referred to by that name.  Personally I never say "I'm going to to the barber" but rather "I'm going to get a haircut."  The barber shop clientele is also almost exclusively male -- otherwise people (of either gender) will go to a "salon" to see a "stylist".

Comment: @Andrew Are you speaking about a haircutter or a stylist? A barber can be any gender so can a stylist too.

Comment: @SovereignSun  I mean that the term "barber" is not really *used*, at least among people I know.  I've not been to a "barber" to cut my hair since I was very small.  I go to "a guy who cuts my hair".  Other people might call him a "hair stylist".

Comment: Barbershop as a single word dates back to the mid-1500s.

Comment: @Andrew - Maybe it's a regionalism, but here in NYC, "barber" is still alive and well.

Comment: Just a note about "barber's shop": This could be any type of shop, because it is simply a shop owned by a barber. Stylists and even 'Haircutters' have become more common than barbers in Canada, but barbershops still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between

> barbershop
>   barber shop

there is no difference, especially when spoken

[image]

[image]

> barber's shop

is an older way of referring to the first two and will make you sound elderly.

> I want to cut my hair

sounds like you are going to cut your own hair, whereas most natives would say

> I want to **get** my hair cut...
>
> I'm **getting** my hair cut...
>   I'm **going to get**  my hair cut...

and these days with so much branding

> I'm going to *Supercuts* / *Paul Mitchell* / *Vidal Sassoon*.

instead of *the barber's* or *barber shop*.

Comment: Why not have a haircut? Have my hair cut?